# What happens if magic jar ends and the caster's body is undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, undead, soul

Suppose I cast [*magic jar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar) and possess a body, then I kill my old body and cast [*animate dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) on it, and after that I break the magic jar.
What happens when the soul returns to the zombified body?

For reference, *magic jar* says the following:

> If the container is destroyed or the spell ends, your soul immediately returns to your body. If your body is more than 100 feet away from you or if your body is dead when you attempt to return to it, you die.

Comment: I don’t really see how that question is a duplicate, but if it solves your problem, I guess that’s cool.

Comment: I don't think that flagging it as duplicate is a good thing, as it isn't one. I think that opening it again and getting an actual answer to this question is a good thing, even if the linked question answers your question, it might help others you might be really curious about your question. If you really don't want this question answered, then I think deleting it would be better, avoid people reading it thinking that this is a real dupe.

Comment: I've reopened this, as the fact the the caster's body died and has been reanimated via necromancy is a substantial difference from being polymorphed. This is a good question and deserves a proper treatment.

Answer (score 4):

### Your body is dead

Even though it’s still moving around. You killed your (humanoid) body - so it’s dead. The (undead) body is not yours.

Comment: The operative word in "shambling corpse" isn't "shambling".

Comment: Isn't "undead" just a creature type? Or are you saying that *true polymorph* into any non-humanoid means dead body?

Comment: And to add to the semantic argument, don't you have to "Kill" liches and the like?   The lich is still "alive" until it's hp drop to zero....

Comment: Even though its a short answer I agree with it. Your body died, then it was animated. The body isn't yours anymore, it's the zombies.